# UnicodeDecodeError ('utf-8') for pandas read_csv from folder nested Zip File

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, zip

I currently have a zip file which contains a list of N folders, each containing 1+ .csv files. I am looking to simply read in a selection of these .csv files from the zip and use pandas to create a list of DataFrames.

I've done this successfully the 'manual' way where I unzip the files locally and just read in the individual .csv's.

However, when I use a zipfile method but I'm getting the following error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xab in position ****: invalid start byte

I thought this would be a straight forward task, but I seem to be missing some step.  I've given my code below. However I suspect the issue is rooted in the way zipfile unpacks the documents compared to macOS (technically The Unarchiver).I have generated a test zip file and successfully got a pandas DataFrame output.  I'm just getting myself mixed up on how to achieve the same result on the 'real' data.

Sadly I am not able to post the original data in question here.

```
import pandas as pd
import zipfile

# Sample loader for testing
sample_path = "Sample_ZipFile.zip"
with ZipFile(sample_path) as zipfiles:

sample_file_names = [file.filename for file in zipfiles.infolist() if file.filename[-4:]=='.csv']
data = zipfiles.open(sample_file_names[0])
testdat = pd.read_csv(data,dtype='str',index_col=False)
```

Comment: I felt a little silly asking this question, as there is obvious just some simple encoding errors going on. But there is an additional observation I've made. 

When running the same notebook through Jupyter Notebook, locally on my machine, and calling the same data files pre-extracted, the pd.read_csv() func works fine. However doing exactly the same thing from a Google Colab hosted instanced (with some slight changes to dir path), I get the encoding error. 

Could the issue be in how Google Colab handles the encoding with Pandas?

Comment: For reference, I found a similar discussion of the problem, but it is unclear how they 'fixed' it. [see here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26124)

Answer (score 1):

So after some frustrated searching the next morning, I eventually stumbled across a similar problem in the Pandas github page which [you can look at here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32392).

It simply seems to be down to a difference in how Google Colab and Jupyter handle pandas (pd) pd.read_csv (and [pd.to_csv](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26124)).

For anyone stumbling across the same error, I managed to get through the problem using:

1. Adding `engine='python'` to `pd.read_csv()`
2. OR adding `encoding='cp1252'` which a colleague suggested.

I am assuming I was just lucky in my Jupyter Notebooks up until now in not seeing any encoding bugs. But I hope this answer helps anyone who might get as stuck as I did...